# How to get this finish on a ceiling?

Tags: ceiling, plaster, renovation, wallpaper

The ceiling in this image is very typical of houses built in the 90s in the UK. Wondering if this type of finish is still available and what it would be called? I'm guessing its a kind of wallpaper that was put over the ceiling boards.

It also has a flat border around the edges next to the coving, any idea how to achieve that kind of finish?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google "textured painted ceiling" to find a wide variety of materials and tools including rollers with various textures. The edges were probably done last with a small roller that has no texture.

Answer (score 2):

This is done with a special roller and common plaster/mud.  It's just sort of hackle-dackle spackled on there, really amazingly cheap.

The purpose is to roughen the surface to conceal lack of parallelness in the ceiling panels, drywall taping lines, hole patches, and other surface defects.

Answer (score 1):

In the UK that type of finish would almost certainly be produced with Artex - a product that is still available in the UK, though I don't know about other countries.

My father used to produce the edge feature simply by running a paint brush along the edge after the main texturing was completed.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the whole ceiling, it looks like a stomped texture with a subtle knock-down. The smooth edge next to the trim, was most likely done with a drywall knife or clean brush. This is a common finish in the US, that has been around for many, many decades.